# Prototyping in javascript to add a new method to bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, prototype

I have just some basic understanding of prototyping in JavaScript.
What I would like to achieve is to extend the 'getdate' method of the ([bootstrap-datepicker plugin](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)).

I don't know why, that plugin does not expose the date as a simple property, but you have to call the `.datepicker('getDate')` method to read the date selected by the user.

I need to get the date in the YYYYMMDD format, so I did this:

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function () {
  var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = this.getDate().toString();
  return yyyy + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]);
};
```

If I read the value like this: `$('#myControl').datepicker('getDate').yyyymmdd();`
it works, unless there is no date selected. In that case, the `datepicker('getDate')` method returns null, and an exception is risen when calling the `yyyymmdd()` method on null. I would like to have instead a null returned.

I tried to prototype the `.datepicker()` method with this code:

```
$().datepicker.prototype.getYyyymmddDate = function () {
  var x = this('getdate');
  if (x != null)
    return x.yyyymmdd();
  else
    return null;
};
```

(of course having prototyped the Date object as above). But trying to read with `$('#myControl').datepicker().getYyyymmddDate();` does not work.

How could I do this?

Comment: When you call the `datepicker` method on the empty jquery selector, you are not setting the prototype anything, that is just executing the function. You need to set your method to the `jQuery` object itself if you want to extend jquery. But you can't "extend" a pre-existing method in the way that I think you want to; in order to do that you would need to modify the bootstrap sourcecode. Also, there is a config option for different date formats http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuration

Comment: I would suggest changing the name of the question into something more appropriate like 'How to add new methods on bootstrap datepicker'

Comment: Not sure why you can't just use the standard `getDate` and then format it?

Answer (score 1):

Well `.datepicker('getDate')` will return a Date object (or null) so changing the `$.fn.datepicker.prototype` won't help.

However, when you pass the 'getDate' option, the plugin checks if there is a method with that name on `$.fn.datepicker.Constructor.prototype`.
So you can do something like

```
$.fn.datepicker.Constructor.prototype.getYyyymmddDate = function () {
   var date = this.getDate();

   if (!date) {
      return null;
   }

   var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
   var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
   var dd = date.getDate().toString();

   return yyyy + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]);
};
```

Then, you can call it like this

```
$('#myControl').datepicker("getYyyymmddDate")
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently, there's already an option called "getFormattedDate", which does what you want (if it can't find a date, it will return an empty string instead of null).

```
$('#myControl').datepicker("getFormattedDate", "yyyymmdd")
```

Comment: Great, Stefan, thanks. I wonder why the `getFormattedDate` method is not listed in the in the documentation for the datepicker plugin I linked above!